# get checked radio button in a group based on a recorded number in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have an int(1) data type in mysql for a radio button group, so how can I get the checked radio button in the group based on the recorded number in mysql (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), in order to show it already checked?

This is the asp net code for the radio button group

```
<asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="ESTUDIOS" Width="140px" Height="20px"/>&nbsp;
     <p>
          <asp:RadioButton ID="RBNEst1" runat="server" GroupName="GrupoEstudios" Text="Básicos" Enabled="False"/>
     </p>
     <p>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RBNEst2" runat="server" GroupName="GrupoEstudios" Text="Medios" Enabled="False"/>
     </p>
     <p>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RBNEst3" runat="server" GroupName="GrupoEstudios" Text="Técnicos" Enabled="False"/>
     </p>
     <p>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RBNEst4" runat="server" GroupName="GrupoEstudios" Text="Universitarios" Enabled="False"/>
     </p>
     <p>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RBNEst5" runat="server" GroupName="GrupoEstudios" Text="Incompleto" Enabled="False"/>
     </p>
```

and this is the c# code to record the checked radio button

```
if (RBNEst1.Checked) { datos.nivelestudios = 1; }
else if (RBNEst2.Checked) { datos.nivelestudios = 2; }
else if (RBNEst3.Checked) { datos.nivelestudios = 3; }
else if (RBNEst4.Checked) { datos.nivelestudios = 4; }
else if (RBNEst5.Checked) { datos.nivelestudios = 5; }
```

Comment: so whats the question

Comment: how can I get the checked radio button based on the recorded number, in order to show it checked in the group?

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer that I found, although I'd like to find a way to simplify the code for many radiobuttons

```
if (fila["nivelestudios"].ToString() == "1") { RBNEst1.Checked = true; }
else if (fila["nivelestudios"].ToString() == "2") { RBNEst2.Checked = true; }
else if (fila["nivelestudios"].ToString() == "3") { RBNEst3.Checked = true; }
else if (fila["nivelestudios"].ToString() == "4") { RBNEst4.Checked = true; }
else if (fila["nivelestudios"].ToString() == "5") { RBNEst5.Checked = true; }
```